# ScrapydWeb: Connection refused within docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, scrapy, scrapyd

I tried to run a couple of scrapyd services to have a simple cluster on my localhost, but only the first node works. For 2 others I get the following error

```
scrapydweb_1      | [2020-11-17 07:17:32,738] ERROR    in scrapydweb.utils.check_app_config: HTTPConnectionPool(host='scrapyd_node_3', port=6802): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb060b8ef50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
scrapydweb_1      | [2020-11-17 07:17:32,738] ERROR    in scrapydweb.utils.check_app_config: HTTPConnectionPool(host='scrapyd_node_2', port=6801): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fb060a1e650>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  scrapyd_node_1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./crawlers/scrapyd/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6800:6800"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/scrapyd
      - ./data/results:/app/results
    restart: unless-stopped

  scrapyd_node_2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./crawlers/scrapyd/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6801:6800"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/scrapyd
      - ./data/results:/app/results
    restart: unless-stopped

  scrapyd_node_3:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./crawlers/scrapyd/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "6802:6800"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/scrapyd
      - ./data/results:/app/results
    restart: unless-stopped


  scrapydweb:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./crawlers/scrapydweb/Dockerfile
    environment:
      USERNAME: "test"
      PASSWORD: "test"
      SCRAPYD_SERVERS: "scrapyd_node_1:6800,scrapyd_node_2:6801,scrapyd_node_3:6802"
    links:
      - scrapyd_node_1
      - scrapyd_node_2
      - scrapyd_node_3
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - scrapyd_node_1
      - scrapyd_node_2
      - scrapyd_node_3

    restart: unless-stopped
```

What is wrong with my docker-compose file?

Comment: I am not sure, but check this line: `SCRAPYD_SERVERS: "scrapyd_node_1:6800,scrapyd_node_2:6801,scrapyd_node_3:6802"`; For instance scrapyd_node2 have opened port 6800 (in container), and on your localhost it is port 6801. Try changing that to: `SCRAPYD_SERVERS: "scrapyd_node_1:6800,scrapyd_node_2:6800,scrapyd_node_3:6800"`.

Comment: @DawidGacek thank you so much. You can post it as a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in line:

```
SCRAPYD_SERVERS: "scrapyd_node_1:6800,scrapyd_node_2:6801,scrapyd_node_3:6802"
```

Try changing it to:

```
SCRAPYD_SERVERS: "scrapyd_node_1:6800,scrapyd_node_2:6800,scrapyd_node_3:6800"
```

Explanation:

When you defined you docker service `scrapyd_node_2` for instance, you defined ports to be:

```
    ports:
      - "6801:6800"
```

It means, that port `6800` from contanier is mapped to port `6801` on your host machine. Hence, when you want to declare node with hostname `scrapyd_node_2`, you should use it's port = `scrapyd_node_2:6800`.